Exercise 5.16 of Atiyah and Macdonald

Noether’s normalization lemma Let $k$ be an infinite field and let $A \neq 0$ be a finitely generated $k$-algebra. Then there exist elements $y_1,…,y_r\in A$ which are algebraically independent over $k$ and such that $A$ is integral over $k[y_1,…,y_r]$.
Hint We shall assume $k$ is infinite. Let $x_1, \dots , x_n$ generate $A$ as a $k$-algebra. [ We can renumber the $x_i$ so that $x_1, \dots , x_r$ are algebraically independent over $k$ and each of $x_{r+1}, \dots , x_n$ is algebraic over $k[x_1, \dots , x_r]$]. Now proceed by induction on $n$. If $n=r$ there is nothing to do, so suppose $n\gt r$ and the result true for $n−1$ generators. The generator $x_n$ is algebraic over $k[x_1,…,x_{n−1}]$,
hence there exists a polynomial $f\neq 0$ in $n$ variables such that $f(x_1,…, x_{n−1}, x_n) = 0$. Let $F$ be the homogeneous part of highest degree in $f$. Since $k$ is infinite, there exist $\lambda_1,…,\lambda_{n−1} \in k$ such that $F(\lambda_1,… , \lambda_{n−1}, 1)\neq 0$. Put $x_i’ = x_i−λ_ix_n$ ($1\leq i \leq n−1$). Show that $x_n$ is integral over the ring $A’
= k[x_1’,…, x_{n−1}’]$ and hence that $A$ is integral over $A’$. Then apply the inductive hypothesis to $A’$ to complete the proof.

Question: Without loss of generality assume $x_1, \dots , x_r$ are independent over $k$ and $x_{r+1}, \dots , x_n$ are dependent over $k$, therefore over $k[x_1, \dots , x_r]$. In inductive step, $x_n$ is dependent over $k$. Then $\exists 0\neq f\in k[X_1]$ such that $f(x_n)=\sum_{i=0}^ma_ix_n^i=0$. Multiply by $a_m^{-1}$, we get $$x_n^m+a_m^{-1}a_{m-1}x_n^{m-1}+\cdots +a_m^{-1}a_0=0.$$
So $x_n$ is integral over $k$, therefore over $A’$. We are not using the fact that $k$ is infinite. I must be missing something obvious.

Oh I love exercise $5.16$  @carlossantos

How are you assuming wlog that $x_{r+1}, \ldots, x_{n}$ are dependent over ${\color{red}k}$? For example, if $A = k[x^2, xy, y^2] \subset k[x, y]$, what will you take as $x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}$?

@AryamanMaithani wlog is essentially same as renumber. If $x_i$ for some $r+1\leq i\leq n$ is independent over $k$, then that contradicts maximality of $r$.

You miss my point: you may assume that $x_{r+1}, \ldots, x_{n}$ are dependent over $k[x_{1}, \ldots, x_{r}]$, not over $k$.

@AryamanMaithani $x_1=x^2$ and $x_2=y^2$ are independent over $k$, since $x,y$ are indeterminate. $x_3=xy$ is dependent over $k[x^2,y^2]$, since $x_3$ satisfy polynomial $X^2-x^2y^2\in k[x^2,y^2][X]$. Also $x_3=xy$ is independent over $k$, since polynomial in two indeterminate is zero iff all coefficients of that polynomial is zero. This shows my interpretation of hint is wrong.

In your proof written in the question, you end up using that $x_n$ satisfies a polynomial equation over $k$: that is not correct.

@AryamanMaithani yaa I have realized that. In corollaries of Noether normalization lemma, I also need to use $k[y_1,…,y_r]$ is isomorphic to polynomial rings in $r$ variable. But I don’t think $y_i$ ($1\leq i\leq r$) are independent over $k$ is enough to prove $k[y_1,…,y_r]\cong k[X_1,…,X_r]$. We have to assume $y_i$ is independent over $k[y_1,…,y_{i-1}]$ for all $1\leq i\leq r$. Am I right?

We actually need to fill detail of [$\cdots$] sentence. Choose an arbitrary generator $x_1$ such that $x_1$ is independent over $k$. Choose generator $x_2$ such that $x_2$ is independent over $k[x_1]$. Continue this process. After finite iteration, say $r$, there exist no generator $x_i$ such that $x_i$ is independent over $k[x_1,…,x_r]$. So we get $x_{r+1},…,x_n$ are dependent over $k[x_1,…,x_r]$. In inductive step, $x_n$ is dependent over $k[x_1,…,x_r]\subseteq k[x_1,…,x_{n-1}]$.
Given our construction of $\{x_1,…,x_r\}$, we have $k[X_1,…,X_r]\cong k[x_1,…,x_r]$. Define $$\phi :k[X_1,…,X_r]\to k[x_1,…,x_r]$$ given by $X_i\mapsto x_i$ and $\phi$ is identity on $k$. It is easy to check, $\phi$ is epimorphism. If $\phi (f)=f(x_1,…,x_r)=0$ for some $f\neq 0$, then $x_i$ is dependent over $k[x_1,…,x_{i-1}]$ for some $1\le i\leq r$. Which is a contradiction. So $f=0$ and $\phi$ is isomorphism.
Note $\{x_1,…,x_r\}$ is algebraically independent over $k$$\iff$$x_i$ is independent over $k[x_1,…,x_{i-1}]$ for all $1\leq i\leq r$$\implies$$k[X_1,…,X_r]\cong k[x_1,…,x_r]$.
